# Is there a way to add name resolution without modifying /etc/hosts file?

Tags: java, macos, dns

I wanted to add a new alias name for "localhost" so that a Java program can run locally. Is it possible to do that without modifying /etc/hosts file?

i.e.  "myserver" should be resolved into "localhost" when running a particular Java application.

OS: MacOS
Program:  Java

I searched for JVM arguments, Java system properties, environment variables, but cannot find a solution.

Comment: Have you tried dnsmasq?

Comment: It seems that dnsmasq is not included in Mac OS by default.  As my program / script is going to be used by others, I cannot assume they have dnsmasq installed.

Comment: Why not just modify the code to connect to `localhost`?

Comment: The code is supposed to connect to a name provided by another application, i.e. not hard-coded.

Comment: It's not unreasonable to have dependencies, particularly if you are providing customised functionality like this. As long as you provide details of what the dependencies are and where to get them, I don't see a problem.